# Apache cassandra and stargate error TSocket read 0 bytes while creating the Index

Tags: cassandra

When creating the index using something similar to http://stargate-core.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-a-row-index I get the following notification in shell

```
TSocket read 0 bytes
```

I am using apache-cassandra-2.0.14 and stargate-core-0.9.5. According to the ticket https://github.com/tuplejump/stargate-core/issues/46 this shouldn't be happening.

Any insight on this is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Found that Stargate is only compatible with apache-cassandra-2.0.7, 2.0.8 and 2.0.9.  Therefore this error will occur for other versions.

Comment: They literally just released version 1.0.0 of stargate a few days ago.  I found this post looking for a little more detail on stargate myself.  The new version works with C* 2.1, I can verify that it works with 2.1.3 of DataStax Community server.